# macのfindコマンド利用と正規表現での移動処理について。

Tags: macos, bash, 正規表現

カレントディレクトリ以下を再帰的に検索して(Aのファイル名)のみを、指定したfolderにコピーではなく、移動したいと考えております。その際（Bのファイル名）は除外したいです。

Aファイル名　abcdefjhij_255169069.jpeg
Bファイル名　abcdefjhij_255169069_Preview.jpeg

テキストエディタの正規表現では下記でうまく動くのですが、macのbashでテストすると正規表現の部分がうまく認識できていないようです。

abcdefjhij_255169069.jpeg
`\w+_\d+\.jpeg`

下記で一つ上の階層のb-folderにpngファイルを移動するテストはうまくいきました。
`find -E . -type f -iregex ".+\.png" -exec mv {} ../b-folder \;`

ですが正規表現の部分変更、テストするとうまくいきません。
`find -E . -type f -iregex "\w+_\d+\.jpeg" -exec mv {} ../b-folder \;`

できれば、カレントディレクトリに作成済みの別ディレクトリに移動（一つ上の階層ではなく）、その時に同じファイル名があった場合は、上書き保存するようにできればと思っております。
宜しくお願い致します。

（追加の文面です。）
ご指摘ありがとうございます｡表現が曖昧でした申し訳ございません｡

試しに `1234.txt` というファイルを作成し試したところ、

`find . -name "1.+4\.txt"` 
`find . -name "[0-9]{4}\.txt"`
`find . -name "1..4\.txt"` 
はいずれもファイル名が表示されずそのままプロンプトに戻ります。

`find . -name "1*4\.txt"`のみ `1234.txt` というファイルが表示されました。
ご指摘頂いた通り、`\d`は使えません。
結論としては`find . -name "a*j_[0-9]*[^a-z].jpeg"` で`abcdefjhij_255169069.jpeg`が表示できたのですが、量指定子が使えないので仮に`abcdefjhijjjjj_255169069999.jpeg`というファイルでも検索されてしまうので、何か良い解決方法はありますでしょうか。

ファイル名の形式としては、アルファベット（10桁)_数値（9桁).jpegのみファイルを移動したいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 「うまく認識できない」「うまくいきません」では曖昧でわかりません。具体的にどのような動作になるのかを記載するようにしましょう。

Comment: 正規表現に関する質問の場合、パターンの部分について詳しく説明した方が回答が付きやすいと思います。例えば「(アルファベット)_(数字).jpeg」なファイル名が対象だけど、「"_Preview"が含まれているものは除外」、など。

Comment: ERE(POSIX 1003.2:Extended Regular Expressions)では `\d` 表記をサポートしていませんので、`[0-9]+` か `[[:digit:]]+` とする必要があります。参考:[Regex cheatsheet](https://remram44.github.io/regex-cheatsheet/regex.html)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。追加の文面としてアップいたしました。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: ええと、追記の部分では find コマンドに `-E` オプションが付いていませんが、何か理由があるのでしょうか？ `-E` オプションを付けない場合、BRE(POSIX Basic Regular Expressions) として解釈されてしまい、量指定子(quantifier)の指定は `\{4\}` などとする必要があります(`{}` をバックスラッシュでエスケープ)。

Comment: それと、追記の部分では `-name` を使用していますので、BRE や ERE ではなくてシェルのパターンマッチング文字列として解釈される事になります。

Comment: 因みに、`find -E . -type f -iregex "[0-9]{4}\.txt"`これでも何も表示されず、プロンプトに戻ってしまうのですが、これも使い方がおかしいのでしょうか。findコマンドで量指定子を使用して、1234.txtだけ表示して12344444.txtは表示しないようにする具体的は方法をご教授して頂ければ助かります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find -E . -type f -iregex ".*\/[a-j]+_[0-9]+\.jpeg"`
でどうでしょうか？

[findの正規表現は完全一致で | テキトーな備忘録](http://tekitobibouroku.blog42.fc2.com/blog-entry-75.html)

上記ページを見て知ったのですが、findのregex系オプションは完全一致しないといけないので、パス（この場合`./`）も一致するようにしないといけないようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。find -E . -type f -iregex ".*\/[a-j]+_[0-9]+\.jpeg" -exec mv {} ../b-folder \;とする事で、一つ上のb-folder に目的のファイルabcdefjhij_255169069.jpegのみ移動できました。